# Google Play Music offline files cannot be found

Tags: files, google-play-music, cache

So I have a very odd problem.  When I mark my songs for offline use in Google Play Music, they download just fine and are available offline. However, when I go to the `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache` directory, there are **no** files in there.

Does anyone know how to find my files or fix what's wrong?

I'm very confused and have already tried factory restoring my phone. I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3 (Verizon) with the stock ROM which I've rooted.

Comment: On my Galaxy Nexus my cached music files are in `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache/music`.

Comment: Use something like Astro and search for "mp3".

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out. Somewhere along the line, Google moved the offline music/cache to `/data/data/com.google.android.music/`.